# Why am I unable to reuse Logback's DBAppender?

Tags: java, logback

I'm using logback's DBAppender to output log messages to a PostgreSQL database. This works well for the initial application I implemented this with, however if I copy my config to another program that also uses logback, it doesn't work. Why?

No error is thrown on the other programs, executions (and logging) continue as if no change to the `logback.xml` file was made.

My config is as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{35}) - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DataSourceConnectionSource">
            <dataSource
                    class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
                <driverClass>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClass>
                <jdbcUrl>jdbc:postgresql://ec2-xxx-21-xxx-162.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6232/mydatabase?user=myuser&amp;password=mypw&amp;ssl=true&amp;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory</jdbcUrl>
            </dataSource>
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="DB" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Tables are created with the PostgreSQL scripts:

```
    -- Logback: the reliable, generic, fast and flexible logging framework.
-- Copyright (C) 1999-2010, QOS.ch. All rights reserved.
--
-- See http://logback.qos.ch/license.html for the applicable licensing 
-- conditions.

-- This SQL script creates the required tables by ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender
--
-- It is intended for PostgreSQL databases.

DROP TABLE    logging_event_property;
DROP TABLE    logging_event_exception;
DROP TABLE    logging_event;
DROP SEQUENCE logging_event_id_seq;


CREATE SEQUENCE logging_event_id_seq MINVALUE 1 START 1;


CREATE TABLE logging_event 
  (
    timestmp         BIGINT NOT NULL,
    formatted_message  TEXT NOT NULL,
    logger_name       VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    level_string      VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    thread_name       VARCHAR(254),
    reference_flag    SMALLINT,
    arg0              VARCHAR(254),
    arg1              VARCHAR(254),
    arg2              VARCHAR(254),
    arg3              VARCHAR(254),
    caller_filename   VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    caller_class      VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    caller_method     VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    caller_line       CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    event_id          BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('logging_event_id_seq') PRIMARY KEY
  );

CREATE TABLE logging_event_property
  (
    event_id          BIGINT NOT NULL,
    mapped_key        VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    mapped_value      VARCHAR(1024),
    PRIMARY KEY(event_id, mapped_key),
    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES logging_event(event_id)
  );

CREATE TABLE logging_event_exception
  (
    event_id         BIGINT NOT NULL,
    i                SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    trace_line       VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(event_id, i),
    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES logging_event(event_id)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue isn't logback as creating a new project works fine.

In this case it appears that the logback configuration is being ignored and log4j is providing the logging.